# I mistakenly renamed my home holder with sudo. Cannot login to system

Tags: 16.04, user-management

I was changing my username. In the process I made a mistake of using following command.

```
$ sudo mv /home/user /home/waqar
```

I thought it would simply rename the home folder. But now cannot even login to my system.

Comment: Enter the recovery mode or boot from liveCD or liveUSB to make your rename. You can boot from recent liveUbuntu; Also see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: I can't recall if this works (I know you won't be able to login via gui as it can't create the necessary work files so it's like a full-disk, you're logged out again), but try a terminal login.  Otherwise I'd use a 'live' system (eg. your Ubuntu install media) to undo what you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you didn't update the password database to tell the system your user's new home directory, so it's still looking for the old one.

You should be able to fix this with `usermod`:

```
usermod -d /home/waqar username
```

(where `username` is the **current** username - it's not clear whether or not you successfully changed the username before you renamed the home directory).

To do so you will either need to login as another administrative user and use `sudo`, or boot into recovery mode, select the root shell option, and re-mount the `/` filesystem in read-write mode using

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

first.

---

For the record, the right way to rename a user's home directory is

```
usermod -m -d /path/to/newhome username
```

which takes care of the moving AND updating the password database. From `man usermod`

```
   -d, --home HOME_DIR
       The user's new login directory.

       If the -m option is given, the contents of the current home
       directory will be moved to the new home directory, which is created
       if it does not already exist.
```

Answer (score 2):

You are in luck - this operation is not hard to reverse.

1. Boot the Ubuntu installation media - do *Try Ubuntu without installing* because we don't want to re-install.
2. Find the drive where Ubuntu is installed in the **Files** application.
3. From there, you can rename your home folder back to what it was before to undo your changes.
4. Now reboot and Ubuntu should boot correctly.

If you want to change your entire username, your only option is to re-install.

Comment: its true this should work. you can also use this way to recover precious data from a windows hdd installment if you cannot get into it anymore

Comment: It's not necessary to reinstall to change one's username, and it's not really a very effective way to do so either. Even if there weren't [a way to do it directly](https://askubuntu.com/a/1171534/22949)--and in the case where bugs in some applications keep that from working without problems--it is still possible to create a new user account, start using that account, *move data over from the old account*, followed optionally by deletion of the old account. Reinstalling Ubuntu would be a way of doing part *but not all* of that. But this answer is very useful and, other than that, correct.